# How to re-use Vue js methods from another blade view

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using `Vue` with `Laravel`, following basically this structure:

[image]

So basically, I'm using a **js file** for each **blade view**. But now I need to find a way to **re-use** those js files for others blade views, and I don't know if it is possible with the structure I'm using.

[image]

Above is an example about what I'm trying to do. Basically, I have a javascript file with Vue methods that I could **reuse**. What I thought is: "Only add the `el:'.reusable-class'` to the `<div>` on the `example.blade.php` and add the `<script src="js/reusable.js"></script>` at the bottom and that's it! I've imported successfully their methods..." But doesn't work.

Other thing I've tried is to call the method just beetween javascript files. something like this:

```
 appExample = new Vue({
  ...
 methods:
    test(){
         appReusable.reusable();
    }
```

And the message I get is: `appExample is not defined`. I've read about it, about how to import another vue component, but it will change my project structure...

What should I do to successfully import and reuse methods from another vue file with my current project structure?

Comment: This is what Vue components are for.  You build a component once, then you can import them into any vue instance. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 2):

The feature your are looking for is called a Vue Component.

See Laravel documentation for quick introduction: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#writing-vue-components

If you used the default front-end scaffold in your Laravel project, you'll find an example Vue Component in the following folder: 
`ressouces >> js >> components >> ExampleComponent.vue`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing it as the example tutorial but doesn't work. I get the `require is not defined` error. Does that mean I need to install `laravel/ui`?

Comment: Install the laravel/ui package and then generate the scaffold for Vue JS:

`composer require laravel/ui --dev`

`php artisan ui vue`

You should then be able to use the example vue-component that comes with Laravel anywhere in your blade files just like if it was a custom HTML tag `<example-component></example-component>`

Don't forget to recompile your assets every time you change your anything in your vue-component using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` during active development.